# Call Azure active directory Password Reset Policy from Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have Azure function, which use Azure Active Directory B2C for authentication.
I use SignUpSignIn flow for login and registration.
When "Forgotten password" is clicked in Login dialog, AAD by design returns error code AADB2C90118 to callback redirect (described [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp/issues/9)).
Azure function ends with "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." error.

How can i handle behavior of Azure function app to our own ResetPassword flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ResetPassword flow should not be working in this way in your Azure Function app.

The SignUpSignIn flow is used as Azure Active Directory B2C authentication for your Function app. So the effective parts are just login and registration.

As we can see in [Linking user flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview#linking-user-flows):

> Clicking this link doesn't automatically trigger a password reset user
>   flow. Instead, the error code AADB2C90118 is returned to your
>   application. Your application needs to handle this error code by
>   running a specific user flow that resets the password.

So when you click on "Forgot your password?", it actually returns the AADB2C90118 error which is by-design. And your function app will will treat it as a login failure， which gives "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." error.

To simply set ResetPassword flow in the function app is not supported. You should create an application and handle AADB2C90118 error in your code and redirect to the ResetPassword flow. It should be finished in your application. Not in the function app authentication. After you reset the password, you can log in and pass the access token to your function to finish the authentication process. See a sample [here](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet-SUSI).